# identification of species of tree

Tags: botany, species-identification

I just want to confirm the species of the tree in the middle of the picture. Is it the "Flame of the Forest"? This is taken in my school campus. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I would be good to be able to see the leaves in detail. This makes an identification easier.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about plant identification. These questions are usually asked on Gardening and Landscaping Stack Exchange.  This topic is not found in the following appropriate topics listing in the Help center:                          1) General questions about biological concepts
2) Questions about the biological mechanisms behind medical conditions
3) Questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a Royal Poinciana tree with the scientific name Delonix regia..

[image]

Please refer to [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delonix_regia) for more info

Answer (score 1):

I actually should write it in comment, but I did to upload a few photos.

From the distant-photo of the tree, I couldn't understand clearly; however from a trace of vertical long patches (long hanging fruits?) it seems to be *Delonix regia*, but I'm not sure.

If you could upload some more close-up photos, focusing more features, it will help. In-fact *Delonix* is easily identifiable.

In-advanced I posted some photo, it will help to think-out how-to capture the  possible important features in photograph.

---

Flowers:

[image: flower and flower bud delonix]

http://chalk.richmond.edu/flora-kaxil-kiuic/d/delonix_regia_MERIDA_06s.JPG 
Flower is approx 8 to 10 cm wide. 1 petal (out-of 5) is different- colored from other, yellowish.  If the Tree is delonix, you'll obtain flower and petals scattered  beneath the tree.

[image: flower, delonix]

http://www.kew.org/files/styles/content_featured/public/Delonix_regia_02_Fl_main_web_2015.jpg

The flowering season is normally late-spring to late-summer.

If it is *Delonix regia*, it would yield fruits like this:

[image: Delonix]
https://txtriffidranch.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/orangebloom_62714_4.jpg

The fruits are [pods (legume-fruits)](http://academics.hamilton.edu/foodforthought/our_research_files/beans_peas.pdf) , flat, big, could be 1 foot to more than a meter; 4 to 6 cm wide. Green and tough when young , but when ripen, become brown, very hard , woody and lose flexibility.

You'll find fallen fruits below the tree, entire fruit and splitted fruit both find. Splitted fruits look like this,

[image: Delonix fruit]http://www.backyardnature.net/q/delonix.jpg

(and this is a good plaything for school-going kids and village kids)

Leaves:

[image: Single leaf]
http://static.memrise.com/uploads/things/images/18258191_130813_1724_38.jpg 
The small leaf-like objects are leaflets of delonix. The single big thing is 1 leaf. The leaf is [pinnately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinnation) compound twice... i.e. bipinnate. with each step of [fractal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal) is paripinnate (even-pinnate). Look the pulvinus.

[image: Leaves]
http://static.memrise.com/uploads/things/images/18258191_130813_1724_38.jpg
This is what several leaves look like.

[phyllotaxy](http://Phyllotaxis) is alternate and spiral-type.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delonix_regia

---

**Are these match to your tree**? If not, then bring me back to reality.